# amazon category list fetching using php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am trying to fetch amazon categories and sub categories and then add my tracking id to the category url. The 2nd part I can manage but can't figure out how to do the first part. If I can get a page where all the categories and sub-categories is listed...I can fetch the urls from there using cURL. I have done the following code to fetch offers...

```
$url = "https://affiliate-program.amazon.in/offers";
 $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.897.0 Safari/535.6'); 

  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();

@$dom->loadHTML($data);


$k = "My Tracking ID";

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr) {

$name = '';
        $price = '';

foreach($tr->getElementsByTagName('td') as $link) {

if($link->getAttribute('class') == 'leftcell') {
 foreach($link->getElementsByTagName('img') as $i) {

        $img_link = $i->getAttribute('src');

echo $img_link . "&trackid="$k;
 }

}
}
}
```

I could have done this as I know the offer page url for affiliates but I don't have the page url from where I can fetch the all category lists

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Perhaps show some code? If you show what you have tried, that doesn't produce the desired result, and then what that desired result is, you will more easily get help. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @swalog...hope my effort on achieving the target is ok...I just need the page where the categroies are listed...rest coding I can take care

Comment: @swalog...have you checked what i have tried so far

Comment: There is no need to ask me, I have no intention of answering it. I only suggested how you could improve your question, so that someone else might be inclined to answer it.